# Firebase data not showing in web

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to show all the data from a specific table in Firebase by doing this

There are total of 4 data, p1 - p4, in this table however, it only shows 1 result.

JS:

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(uid + '/pickUp');
 var query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
 query.on("child_added", function(messageSnapshot) {
                    var keys = Object.keys(messageSnapshot);
                    var messageData = messageSnapshot.val();
                    var key = messageSnapshot.getKey();
                    console.log("key is " + messageSnapshot.getKey());
                    console.log("messagesnapshot is " + messageSnapshot);
                    console.log("messageData is " + messageData);
                        s = "<div><input type='text' name='pickUp[]' value='messageData'>" + key + "</div>";

                    var obj = {
                        key: key,

                    };
                    arr.push(obj);

  $("#container1").html(s);
 console.log("arr.length is " + arr.length);
```

});

HTML:

```
     <label for="basic">Pick Up Location:</label>
     <div id="container1"> 
    </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use append() instead of of html()

```
...
$("#container1").append(s);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help it works. Anyway I just realized that the input value is showing literally messageData. I wanted it to be the value stored in messageData instead. By anychance do you know what needs to be change?

Comment: try this way:
s = "<div><input type='text' name='pickUp[]' value='+ messageData  +'>" + key + "</div>";

Comment: Ive tried and it doesnt work. It will also show literally the value '+ messageData +'.

Comment: sorry, i'm missing quotes,
s = "<div><input type='text' name='pickUp[]' value=' "+ messageData +" '>" + key + "</div>"

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for the helps. Really appreciate it.